# How cut continuous variable on non-equal size intervals by formula in R?

Tags: r, split

Let see the example.

There is a variable 'x'

```
x <– c(1:10)
```

Splitting 'x' on equal-size intervals

```
cut(x, breaks = 3)
```

How to split 'x' into non-equal size intervals by formula like

```
# This is not working code
# cut(x, breaks = 3, size = exp(x))
```

to get results like:

```
(1, 6] (6, 9] (9, 10]
```

The size of observations in each next bin should be less than in previous. So, if we place elements on "x" axis, and a number of observations in each bin on "y" axis - it should be a curve described by an exponential formula:

Bins:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
bins = (1, 6] (6, 9] (9, 10]
x_bin_index = (1, 2, 3)
y_bin_size = (6, 3, 2)
```

The question is how to split original data on such bins

Thanks

Comment: the issue that i have to use formula - not concrete numbers - the original vector 'x' could be any size

Comment: You don't need a function call there `cut(x, breaks = exp(x))`

Comment: i have to have the same 3 bins - but values inside these bins should be distributed exponentially - like >> cut(x, breaks = 3, size = exp(x))

Comment: I don't know what you mean by exponential distribution. In your example there are simply more observations in the first bin than in the second but why do you call exponential distribution?

Comment: Yes, the size of observations in each next bin is less than in previous. So, if we place bin index on "x" axis, and a number of observations in each bin on "y" axis - it should be a curve described by an exponential formula: X = (1, 6] (6, 9] (9, 10] - Y = ( 6, 3, 2). The question is how to split original data on such bins

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the quantile function which maps a quantile (i.e. proportion of area under curve) to an x value. So to get, let's say, 4 equal parts, you would obtain the quantile for 0.25, 0.5, and 0.75. For many distributions, quantile functions are defined, and their names begin with 'q'. E.g. qnorm for normal distribution, qexp for exponential distribution.